# Alpha gradient to layout without affecting the views that are under it

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout, alpha

I have an activity with a camera preview which is in the background, and over it there is a linear layout with a set of view children. Now, what I want to achieve is to set some kind of selector with an alpha gradient to this linear layout, which affects the linear layout's children BUT without affecting the camera preview that is under it.

Something like this:

[image]

How can I do this? I tried to set a background and making an special view for it but the views below (the camera preview) is always affected by the alpha gradient.

Thanks.

Comment: post an image with what you want to achieve

Comment: what you need is a custom `ViewGroup` that overrides `dispatchDraw` method